# Why would TreeView control send ASCII notifications instead of Unicode ones?

Tags: windows, unicode, dialog, treeview, resource-files

I would like to know what could cause the TreeView control to send ASCII notifications instead of Unicode ones.

In my program I have a child dialog defined in the resource file like this:

```
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
IDD_TREEVIEW DIALOG 0, 0, 165, 434
STYLE DS_SHELLFONT | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILDWINDOW
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{
    CONTROL         "", IDOBJECTTREE, WC_TREEVIEW, WS_TABSTOP | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS, 2, 2, 161, 84, WS_EX_LEFT
}
```

Even though my project is set up to Unicode, the TreeView control sends `TVN_SELCHANGEDA` instead of `TVN_SELCHANGEDW`.

Of course, I can change that sending `TVM_SETUNICODEFORMAT` to the control, but I don't know why is it sending ASCII messages, since it always used to send Unicode ones. That only changed recently when I changed a bunch of code. I've probably messed something up but I don't know what it is.

Comment: TreeView generates ANSI messages if it was created by the ANSI version of CreateWindow().  CreateWindowA instead of CreateWindowW.  That's more convoluted in a dialog with code we cannot see, the simplest explanation is that you used DialogBoxA instead of DialogBoxW.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, I've already thought about that. I'm pretty sure I'm using the Unicode version, or at least that's what the macro solves to. I'm going to have a better look at that.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, now it's official. I'm using `CreateDialogParam` which is `CreateDialogParamW`. `WC_TREEVIEW` is `WC_TREEVIEWW` too.